# C# SQL CONNECTION STRING USING TEXTBOX VALUE

Tags: c#, sql, connection-string

I can't call the value of a `textBox` to use as IP Address.

```
private void IDSearch() {
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    SqlConnection sqlConnection2 = new SqlConnection(@"Server='" + txtIPReal.Text +
        "';Database=xstore;User Id=user;Password=pass;");
    cmd3 = sqlConnection2.CreateCommand();
    cmd4 = sqlConnection2.CreateCommand();

    try {
        sqlConnection2.Open();

        // sql code here
    }
    catch (Exception) {
        // exception handling here
    }
}
```

It catches an error. Can anyone help me?

Comment: can you provide that error

Comment: What error/exception did you catch?

Comment: It point to my catch

Comment: catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Connection Error to the Database\n\nPlease coordinate with HD1 to connect to the database", "Connection Failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

Comment: You might want to consider manually putting in the IP Address manually `@"Server=192.168.1.100;Database=xstore;User Id=user;Password=pass;"` and check your work in reproducing the error first. As your question is already pointing that this is happening because of the `txtIPReal.Text` without enough information or work showing your own debugging attempts.

Comment: You also may want to place the `@` in both sections eg, `@"Server='"` and `@"';Database=xstore;User Id=user;Password=pass;"` although, I could argue you don't need the `@` at all in your case.

Comment: ill try your suggestion and get back to you. thanks

Comment: I get error once i have 2 sqlConnection :(

SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("Server=10.230.144.20;Database=xstore;User Id=user;Password=pass");
        //SqlConnection sqlConnection2 = new SqlConnection(@"Server='" + txtIPReal.Text +"';Database=xstore;User Id=user;Password=pass;");

Comment: Are you sure you are able to access SQL through that external IP address?

Comment: and where is your sql instance name, you are giving ip as server but not instance name...

Answer (score 0):

your connection string should be like this

```
@"Data Source="+ txtIPReal.Text +";Integrated Security=False;User ID=user;Password=pass;Initial Catalog=xstore;"
```

you have to follow proper format of connection string [Connection String MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254500(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: it works :) but it is possible to have 2 connection string?

Comment: SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=" + txtIPReal.Text + ";Integrated Security=False;User ID=user;Password=pass;Initial Catalog=xstore;");
            SqlConnection sqlConnection2 = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=False;User ID=user;Password=pass;Initial Catalog=xstore;");

Comment: yes if you save them separately  but you have to set one connection string at a time

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251078/how-to-update-and-accept-answers please check this